# C programming strings, pointers, and allocation

Tags: c, string, parsing, malloc, deep-copy

---

this problem I think is solely a lack of memory allocation issue.

(maybe skip to the bottom and read the final question for some simple suggestions)

I am writing this program that reads file(s) entered by the user. If the file 'includes' other files, then they will be read also. To check if another file includes a file, I parse the first word of the string. To do this I wrote a function that returns the parsed word, and a pointer is passed in that gets set to the first letter of the next word. For example consider the string:

"include foo"              **NOTE** files can only include 1 other file

firstWord == include,       chPtr == f

My algorithm parses firstWord to test for string equality with 'include', it then parses the second word to test for file validity and to see if the file has already been read.

Now, my problem is that many files are being read and chPtr gets overwritten. So, when I return the pointer to the next word. The next word will sometimes contain the last few characters of the previous file. Consider the example files named testfile-1 and bogus:

Let chPtr originally equal testfile-1 and now consider the parsing of 'include bogus':

extracting firstWord will == include, and chPtr will be overwritten to point to the b in bogus. So, chPtr will equal b o g u s '\0' l e - 1. the l e - 1 is the last few characters of testfile-1 since chPtr points to the same address of memory each time my function is called. This is a problem for me because when I parse bogus, chPtr will point to the l. Here is the code for my function:

```
char* extract_word(char** chPtr, char* line, char parseChar)      
//POST: word is returned as the first n characters read until parseChar occurs in line
//      FCTVAL == a ptr to the next word in line
{
   int i = 0;
   while(line[i] != parseChar && line[i] != '\0')                        
  {
     i++;
  }

  char* temp = Malloc(i + 1);            //I have a malloc wrapper to check validity

  for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
  {
     temp[j] = line[j];
  }
  temp[i+1] = '\0';

  *chPtr = (line + i + 1);
  char* word = Strdup(temp);             //I have a wrapper for strdup too
  return word;
```

So, is my problem diagnosis correct? If so, do I make deep copies of chPtr? Also, how do I make deep copies of chPtr?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Why do you `Strdup(temp)` and then return the duplicated copy? If nothing else, you never `free(temp)` so you're leaking memory, and in reality `return temp;` would be just as good (and save you the overhead of a new allocation).

Comment: What do you mean by "This is a problem for me because when I parse bogus, chPtr will point to the l" Wont you stop the parse when the '\0' is found?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly you want to scan a file and when an 'include' directive is encountered you want to scan the file specified in the the 'include' directive and so on ad infinitum for any levels of include i.e. read one file which may include other files which may in turn include other files.....

If that is so (and please correct if I am wrong ) then this is a classic recursion problem. The advantage of recursion is that all variables are created on the stack and are naturally  freed when the stack unwinds.

The following code will do this without any need for malloc or free or the need to make copies of anything:

```
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <sys/stat.h>
 #include <fcntl.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

 #define INCLUDE "include"
 #define INCOFFSET 7

 static void
 process_record (char *name, char *buf)
 {
   // process record here
   printf ("%s:%s\n", name, buf);
 }

 // change this to detect your particular include
 static int
 isinclude (char *buf)
 {
   //printf ("%s:Record %s INCLUDE=%s INCOFFSET=%d\n", __func__, buf, INCLUDE,
 //        INCOFFSET);
   if (!strncmp (buf, INCLUDE, INCOFFSET))
     {
       //printf ("%s:Record == include", __func__);
       return 1;
     }
   return 0;
 }

 static int
 read_file (char *name)
 {

   //printf ("%s:File %s\n", __func__, name);
   FILE *fd = fopen (name, "r");
   if (!fd)
     {
       printf ("%s:Cannot open %s\n", __func__, name);
       return -1;
     }

   char buf[1024];
   ssize_t n;
   while (fgets (buf, sizeof (buf), fd))
     {
       size_t n = strcspn (buf, "\n");
       buf[n] = '\0';
       //printf ("%s:Buf %s\n", __func__, buf);
       if (isinclude (buf))
         {
            read_file (buf + (INCOFFSET + 1));
         }
       else
         {
            process_record (name, buf);
         }
     }
   fclose (fd);

   return 0;
 }

 int
 main (int argc, char *argv[])
 {

   int ret = read_file (argv[1]);
   if (ret < 0)
     {
       exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
     }
   exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char* temp = Malloc(i + 1);            //I have a malloc wrapper to check validity

for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
{
   temp[j] = line[j];
}
temp[i+1] = '\0';  <------- subscript out of range replace with temp[i] = '\0';
```

Comment: Thanks for finding this. But this does not fix my problem as my chPtr's are still being overwritten.

Comment: I do not see char* chPtr in the file, which value is being overwritten in the code you provided.

Comment: Also in the event that the string hits the null terminator, you will be passing back a nextWord that points to outside of the buffer range, that will introduce undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear where your problem is.  But you might use a tool to help locate it.

Valgrind is one such (free) tool.  It will detect a variety of memory access errors.  (It likely would not have found your temp[i+1]='\0' error because that isnt "very wrong").

Our [CheckPointer](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/MemorySafety) tool is another  tool.  It finds errors Valgrind cannot (e.g., e.g., it should have found your buggy temp assignment).  While it is commercial, the evaluation version handles programs of small size, which may work for you.  (I'm at home and don't remember the limits).